# Display tabs don't appear when files and folders are selected in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, parameters

My setup: QGIS 2.8.1 Wien on OS X 10.10.2

I'm a complete beginner at GIS and I'm having trouble on getting the Param/Metadata/Preview/Attributes tabs to appear in the Display Window. When I select a folder or .shp file in the browser, nothing happens. The documentation I'm using shows this as what is supposed to appear when selecting a file or folder:

[image: doc]

I'm getting this:

[image: me]

I've been able to find Metadata, Attributes, and Preview through other methods (Metadata by right clicking on the file, Preview by dragging file to Display Window, and Attributes by dragging file to Display Window and clicking the Open Attribute Table button), but I haven't been able to view Param at all.